# Installed Django 1.9 but Virtual Environment uses 1.8.7

Tags: python, django, django-admin, virtualenv, django-manage.py

I'm trying to use a new version of `Django (1.9)`. I've created a **virtual environment** (venv) in which I've installed  new `Django (1.9)`. Everything seems to work correctly but when I do `manage.py runserver` it seems that it uses older version of `Django (1.8.7)`.

My `venv` is activated so I don't know why it behaves this way.

I'm attaching `cmd` commands from scratch:
[image]

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Please copy and paste text as code quote.

Answer (score 6):

I guess manage.py uses system-wide python executable: look at its shebang (first line). Try running `python manage.py ...`

Comment: Thanks, it works. But do I have to write python before each command?

Comment: This script has a shebang (first line indicating what program this script will be run with). So when you run it as stand-alone executable - the system-wide python is used. Thats why you need to run python manage.py, not manage.py.

Comment: This is WIndows. The shebang doesn't work, but `.py` will be associated to the system Python install. When you `activate`, your `%PATH%` is updated to use the virtualenv Python. You will have to use `python manage.py`.

Comment: The shebang line works on windows from py3.3 with the python launcher. How can it otherwise be that the manage.py call works? Before py3.3 you needed to call it with python, but now it should work with the shebang.

Comment: Two suggestions for Windows development (I support a team that has Mac, Windows and Linux developers): use virtualenvwrapper-win, it will make your life much easier: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win Also, you may want to look into using git-bash with the MinGW shell, it is much nicer than cmd.exe: https://git-for-windows.github.io/ Just my two cents, they've made my development life on Windows MUCH nicer!

Answer (score 2):

The shebang line in the manage.py points to the global installed python. If you change it to the venv python it should work as used normally.

Comment: Thanks, what path should I write there? #!/usr/bin/env python. I've tried absolute path (#!C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\vwproject\venv\Scripts python) but it does not work.

Comment: Windows doesn't understand shebangs.

Comment: Have a look at the pip script in the venv. It should have the correct shebang line.

Comment: The shebang line works on windows from py3.3 with the python launcher.